# Scala generics: why two types with the same upper bound are not compatible?

Tags: scala, generics, type-bounds

I am confused with how bounds work in Scala generics. Consider the following:

```
  sealed trait MessageBody
  case class Body1() extends MessageBody
  case class Body2() extends MessageBody
  sealed trait MessageKey[T <: MessageBody]
  case object Key1 extends MessageKey[Body1]
  case object Key2 extends MessageKey[Body2]

  type MessageHandler[B <: MessageBody] = PartialFunction[MessageKey[B], B => Unit]

  abstract class Handler {
    def messageHandler[B <: MessageBody]: MessageHandler[B]
  }

  class ProcessingHandler[ReturnType <: MessageBody](val onSuccess: MessageKey[ReturnType]) extends Handler {
    override def messageHandler[B <: MessageBody]: MessageHandler[B] = {
      case `onSuccess` => success
    }
    def success(msg: ReturnType): Unit = println(msg)
  }
```

This gives me an error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : ReturnType => Unit
 required: B => Unit
             case `onSuccess` => success
                                 ^
```

In my naive understanding, both `ReturnType` and `B` are subtypes of `MessageBody` and thus must be compatible. So why are they not compatible, and how should I write my code to make them compatible?

---

EDIT: The following piece of code works just fine, and if I mix the relation between the `MessageKey` and `MessageBody` instances anywhere, I get a nice compile time error.

```
class ProcessingHandler2 extends Handler {
  override def messageHandler[B <: MessageBody]: MessageHandler[B] = {
    case Key1 => h1
    // case Key1 => h2  // gives compile-time error
    case Key2 => h2
  }
    def h1(x: Body1): Unit = println(x)
    def h2(x: Body2): Unit = println(x)
}

  val handler: Handler = new ProcessingHandler2   
  handler.messageHandler(Key1)(Body1())            
  // handler.messageHandler(Key1)(Body2())  // gives compile-time error
```

EDIT: Obviously, there is no way to compile check this: `handler.messageHandler(Key3)` and this will result in a `MatchError` at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an object of type `ProcessingHandler[Body1]` and then call `messageHandler[Body2]` on it. According to the signature, it should return a `Body2 => Unit`, but you try to return a `Body1 => Unit`. If you were trying to return a `MessageBody => Unit`, that would be fine as `MessageBody` is a superclass of `Body2`, but `Body1` is not. They're both children of the same superclass, but that doesn't make them compatible, that is you can't pass a `Body2` as an argument to a function that takes a `Body1` or vice versa.

Depending on what exactly your requirements are, there are multiple things you could do:

You could make `Handler` generic instead of `messageHandler` and then extend `Handler[ReturnType]` (or you could give `Handler` a member type and use it in `messageHandler`).

Or you could make `success` take a `MessageBody` as its argument instead of a `ReturnType`.

Comment: In case I call `messageHandler[Body2]` on an object of type `ProcessingHandler[Body1]` I expect a compile time error. For the very same reason, I cannot make `success` take a `MessageBody` because then I lose static type safety. And I cannot make `Handler` generic because it also has other subclasses that have many message handler methods with various signatures.

Comment: @Mahdi That's not how generics work, nor would this be a valid implementation of the interface. Your interface is saying "the method `messageHandler` takes a type parameter that must be a subclass of `MessageBody`". So if you have an implementation of that interface and you call it with a type parameter that is a subclass of `MessageBody` there is no possible reason why it should not compile. The problem is that your implementation of the interface does something that only works with certain type parameters. That's an error in the implementation, not the usage of the method.

Comment: The edited question shows the type of compile-time errors I expect and which I do get. I would appreciate if you could also help me with an example of how you expect things to go wrong while the compiler cannot find them.

Comment: @Mahdi Yeah, but there you're calling the method in a way that contradicts its signature. In the case I described, you wouldn't be. To make this clearer: consider a function that takes an argument `h: Handler` and then calls `h.messageHandler[Body1]`. You're saying that such a call should compile if `h` is a `ProcessingHandler[Body1]`, but not if `h` is a `ProcessingHandler[Body2]`. But all we know about `h` is that it's a handler, so how could that possibly work?

Comment: @Mahdi To expand on that: In your working example, you can call both `messageHandler[Body1]` and `messageHandler[Body2]` without problem. In your non-working example, you can't, but your signature promises that you should be able to. So you need another signature (specifically `messageHandler` must not take a type parameter if it's only able to work with `ResultType` - it should just use `ResultType` directly, which my suggested solution #1 would achieve).

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. If I define `override def messageHandler: MessageHandler[ReturnType] = {` Then I get `error: method messageHandler overrides nothing.`

Comment: @Mahdi What does your current version of `Handler` look like and your `extends` line?

Comment: Like in the question. I posted the only line that changed.

Comment: @Mahdi My suggestion was to make `Handler` generic instead of `messageHandler` and then extending `Handler[ResultType]`.

Comment: Regarding calling the `messageHandler` using a wrong key, please see my second edit.

Comment: And if I make `Handler` generic, how can I implement `ProcessingHandler2` (in my first edit)?

Comment: @Mahdi You can't. `ProcessingHandler` and `ProcessingHandler2` don't behave the same way, so they can't implement the same interface.